# jquery selector: detect deviant class

Tags: jquery, css, selector

here's my markup:

```
<div class='seat'></div>
<div class='seat marked'></div>
<div class='seat marked'></div>
<div class='seat marked'></div>
<div class='seat'></div>
<div class='seat marked'></div>
<div class='seat'></div>
<div class='seat'></div>
```

as a simple binary optical translation this would be:
-xxx-x--

what i want to determine is if the group/range of elements containing the class "marked" has a gap of at least one element which does NOT have class "marked".
any ideas which would be the best approach?

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "empty" element ? Are you regarding to the underlying html or text to be empty ?

Comment: no i meant detecting a "set" of divs which have class "marked" and then detect if there's at least one div which does NOT contain "marked"

Comment: What exactly is the expected result? Can you give an example? It’s still not clear, where exactly the “gap” should be detected and how it’s supposed to relate to the marked seats.

Comment: Are you trying to determine something like: "Are there any unmarked seats between seat 2 and seat 6?"

Comment: shodev yes, exactly :D - in simple terms: it should detect the group itself (first and last marked element which are located side by side) then detect if there's an unmarked seat in between

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to check if there is a gap , you may do the following :

```
$('.marked').nextUntil(":not(.marked)").length == ($('.marked').length - 1)
```

`nextUntil` would actually give you the items in sequence while excluding `.marked` from the selector using `:not` operator.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/bneen5rc/2/

If you are trying to find the element :

```
var matchFound = false;
var firstInstance = false;
$('div').each(function()
{
   if($(this).hasClass('marked') && $(this).hasClass('seat'))
   {
      matchFound = true;
      firstInstance = true;
   }
   else
     matchFound = false;

     if(!matchFound && firstInstance)
     {
       console.log("marked sequence changed");
       return false;
     }

});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/bneen5rc/3/

Answer (score 0):

If I Understand your question rightly then i believe you are trying to build a seat selector, in that way my suggestion will be to use jquery or javascript to do the Job. Like allocating an "id" for each  with numbers, and use onmouseclick to call a javaScript function to eg:-

```
<div id="1" class='seat' onmouseClick="javascript:toggleMarkVal('1');"></div>
<div id="2" class='seat marked' onmouseClick="javascript:toggleMarkVal('2');"></div>
<div id="3" class='seat marked' onmouseClick="javascript:toggleMarkVal('3');"></div>
<div id="4" class='seat marked' onmouseClick="javascript:toggleMarkVal('4');"></div>
<div id="5" class='seat' onmouseClick="javascript:toggleMarkVal('5');"></div>
<div id="6" class='seat marked' onmouseClick="javascript:toggleMarkVal('6');"></div>
<div id="7" class='seat' onmouseClick="javascript:toggleMarkVal('7');"></div>
<div id="8" class='seat' onmouseClick="javascript:toggleMarkVal('8');"></div>
```

now in jQuery
u can create a function to get all the seat numbers 
and inside the function u can create a array (depending on numbers of rows{u can play with it} create number of dimensions) 
in my case im thinking of a 2 row 4 column

If you want me to write the script for jquery please post me, i will.

My Apologies if i have made any errors, anybody can feel to correct it, the above suggestion was taken from my own experience.

Thanks & Regards
Nair

Comment: `onmouseClick` ? Seems you might research this

Comment: is their is any wrong my dear friend Mark Schultheiss. If so please correct me. :) Coz i used this method once for a Online entrance test seat allocation, for students to opt their seats, and it was a room 8x9 seats. So if u have any good idea it will help me to.. Thanks

Comment: There is no `onmouseCilck` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers. Further more there is no need for in-line JavaScript.